# Unable to obtain Massage Oil after completing The Monster Who Cried Girl achievement

Tags: goosebumps-the-game

So I was working towards full completion of Goosebumps: The Game, however I ran into a bit of an issue when I needed to finish the Night of the Giant Inventory achievement which requires me to have picked up every item in a single playthough.

It turns out the item I'm missing is the Massage Oil, which coincidentally, is in the only room I'm unable to access. The mall security guard has the room blocked off since I finished the The Monster Who Cried Girl achievement prior to realizing my mistake. I also saved after completing that achievement.

So my question is, is there any way to access the Massage Kiosk room after completing the achievement, The Monster Who Cried Girl?